# Does it matter to enter English(US) content over English (Uk) language set as default in Joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I have one confusion about the language used in Joomla site. For example I have set up the default language as English (UK) in Joomla configuration while installation and after that I have installed the virtue-mart with the same language. But the thing is my company is in USA not in UK. So does it matter to upload the English(US) content in virtue-mart or content manger. Or there any other settings in Joomla that we would need to change from UK to United States?

Hope I make it clear what actually I am looking for,Please help me.

Comment: It would be great if you could ask your Joomla related questions over at [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For example I have set up the default language as English (UK) in Joomla configuration while installation and after that I have installed the virtue-mart with the same language. But the thing is my company is in USA not in UK. So does it matter to upload the English(US) content in virtue-mart or content manger.**

Basically every component and plugin which you install in Joomla takes the default language which you setup during the installation i.e English(UK) (Note: Some plugins might have their language packs too). So coming to your question about your company is in USA , I think they I have seen English(UK) in virtuemart Shop tab.You can change this by installing the language packs through install which you can get for Virtuemart in this link : http://virtuemart.net/community/translations/core-modules-plugins-language-packs . You just to need to download the language pack you want and install it.

**Or there any other settings in Joomla that we would need to change from UK to United States?**

For your second question there are no settings in Joomla where you can change from UK to United States you need to intall the packs and make the language which you want to show as the default one.

**One more important thing** please take **backup of your database** before you install the package and make default .As you can see in your db you have categories and products with the language pack as (English (UK)) , once you installed and make default you might see your products and categories hidden (Not deleted you can still see them when you enable the original language pack).So you better take backup and install it.
Hope I clear with your points, let me know if you have further doubts in it.